# Strange type conversion on c# Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Lets have a simple class

```cs
class User
{
   public byte IdByte { get; set; }
}
```

So when I write expressions like these:

```cs
Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression1 = x => x.IdByte == 3;

Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression2 = x => x.IdByte == (byte)3;

byte b = 3;
Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression3 = x => x.IdByte == b;

Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression4 = x => x.IdByte == byte.MaxValue;
```

And watch that expressions debug view, I see that there is an additional type conversion to type System.Int32 :

```cs
//expression1  ------>  x => (Convert(x.IdByte, Int32) == 3)
//expression2  ------>  x => (Convert(x.IdByte, Int32) == 3)
//expression3  ------>  x => (Convert(x.IdByte, Int32) == Convert(value(....c__DisplayClass1_0).b, Int32))
//expression4  ------>  x => (Convert(x.IdByte, Int32) == 255)
```

In first and second expressions  converting right side - 3 to byte is more reasonable than converting left side to int.
In rest of the cases left and right side is byte 
My question is why these conversions applied ?

Comment: A quick test shows that this happens for anything smaller than an int: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AMgJYB2AjgNyEnlV1OUCiCADrADOQ2hHpDWRAMzkspAMKkA3oVLrysjClIBZABQBKFWo1m+gmCLH0APBgCstgK5CAFtAAuAGlKuPUD6kwBAQADYAfBGkCKQAvKT6CL4AnsZx0bFxCSlSZgC+hPlAA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's check [the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#integer-comparison-operators):

> ### Integer comparison operators
>
> The predefined integer comparison operators are:
>
> ```cs
> bool operator ==(int x, int y);
> bool operator ==(uint x, uint y);
> bool operator ==(long x, long y);
> bool operator ==(ulong x, ulong y);
>
> bool operator !=(int x, int y);
> bool operator !=(uint x, uint y);
> bool operator !=(long x, long y);
> bool operator !=(ulong x, ulong y);
>
> bool operator <(int x, int y);
> bool operator <(uint x, uint y);
> bool operator <(long x, long y);
> bool operator <(ulong x, ulong y);
>
> bool operator >(int x, int y);
> bool operator >(uint x, uint y);
> bool operator >(long x, long y);
> bool operator >(ulong x, ulong y);
>
> bool operator <=(int x, int y);
> bool operator <=(uint x, uint y);
> bool operator <=(long x, long y);
> bool operator <=(ulong x, ulong y);
>
> bool operator >=(int x, int y);
> bool operator >=(uint x, uint y);
> bool operator >=(long x, long y);
> bool operator >=(ulong x, ulong y);
> ```
>
> Each of these operators compares the numeric values of the two integer operands and returns a bool value that indicates whether the particular relation is true or false.

As you can see, we don't actually have an `==` operator which compares two `bytes`, or two `sbytes`, `chars`, `shorts`, or `ushorts`.

However, there are implicit conversions from these types to `int`, and so the compiler applies these conversions to both sides, and uses `bool ==(int x, int y)`.

If you write:

```
byte val = 3;
bool b = val == (byte)4;
```

The compiler will effectively turn this into:

```
byte val = 3;
bool b = (int)val == (int)(byte)4;
```

That `(int)(byte)4` cast is of course completely unnecessary: the compiler will just turn this into an integer literal.

```
byte val = 3;
bool b = (int)val == 4;
```

Comment: I note that for actual code (not an Expression), a simple `ceq` is used

Comment: I know you cannot answer that, but "why" would _really_ be interesting...

Comment: because for modern CPU is better to operate on integer type rather than byte

Comment: @Selvin No, it's because there is no IL instruction for `byte` comparison, the IL simply widens to `int` on load, and truncates on store

Comment: *it's because there is no IL instruction for byte* ... and why? what is the root cause?

Comment: Presumably because there's no point? ECMA-335 might have something to say

Comment: @Selvin `and why? what is the root cause?` The IL for bytes seems to always use int32 (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i4_s?view=net-5.0), and your `because for modern CPU is better to operate on integer type rather than byte` hypothesis is the most likely undelying reason.

Answer (score 1):

To build on canton7's Answer.

The reason **why** `bytes`(and other types) in particular are converted into integers is for *language interoperability* by ensuring that the default arithmetic behavior will have identical results on all implementations.

For the specific reason we would have to refer to the Common Language Infrastructure Standard(ECMA-335) that controls **how** the runtime and compiler should handle types, whether on the evaluation or verification stacks respectively.

#### [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf) §III.1.1

> While the [Common Type System] defines a rich type system and the [Common Language Specification] specifies a subset that can be used for
> *language interoperability*, the [Common Language Infrastructure] itself deals with a much simpler set of types.

#### [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf) §III.1.1.1

> The [Common Language Infrastructure] only operates on the numeric types  int32 (4-byte signed integers), int64
> (8-byte signed integers), native int (native-size integers), and F (native-size
> floating-point numbers).

#### [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf) §III.1.1.1.2's Note

> Short (i.e., 1- and 2-byte) integers are loaded as 4-byte numbers on all architectures
> and these 4-byte numbers are always tracked as distinct from 8-byte numbers. This helps
> portability of code by ensuring that the default arithmetic behavior will have identical results on all implementations.